# Ideas for [transparency] tagging

Tags: discussion, tags

The [transparency](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transparency) tag is associated with two meanings, which hinders its use in searches:

- The clear plastic film used for overlays, overhead projectors, etc.
- The transparent property of light transmission, e.g., how to dye resin a transparent color.

People looking for one or the other will need to wade through irrelevant posts.  If we can fix this now, it will be a simple job because there are still only five questions.

People will continue to use [transparency](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transparency) for both meanings because it is ambiguous, and defining the tag won't eliminate that.

My suggestion is to create two unambiguous tags: [transparency-sheets](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transparency-sheets) and [transparent](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transparent) (and define them).

Thoughts, ideas, alternate suggestions?

Comment: Do we actually need the second meaning as a tag? I feel it is more circumstantial to a question.

Comment: @Joachim, in this case, I think it adds value. 1. It's a defining & differentiating characteristic and specific objective that comes up frequently (and it's fundamentally different from a tag like [blue]). 2. People think of it as a defining characteristic or requirement, and want to tag it as such, so they'll find a way (they'll create it if we don't, or will misuse available similar tags). 3. It adds useful context for readers scanning the main page; might help to sort readers or attract an answerer. 4. It's a likely search term.

Comment: I like the idea, but my first gut reaction was to call it "transparent-film" (as a name of an object) and "transparency" (as a property of a material).

Comment: @Elmy, interesting, we're thinking about this from opposite directions (that's probably the same reason why tag usage gets so mixed). "Transparent-film" is technically correct and sounds more "generic". I was shooting for the term that people think of when they see a piece of that film. But it just occurred to me that "transparency" as a term for the film might vary internationally (that's what would pop into the minds of Americans). I landed on "transparent" for the optical property because that would never be used as the term for the film.

Comment: @Elmy, I was thinking about your comment. I had meant to write "transparency-sheets", but your "transparent-film" opens up something else. I don't know if people would connect that with overhead project sheets, but there are a host of transparent films used in crafting, and those would fall under the same meaning (but they wouldn't be associated with transparency sheets). I couldn't spot any existing questions. Would we want people to use [transparent-film] for say a question about using plastic food wrap? Maybe this would be a case for synonomizing the two.

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes, a "sheet" means something different than a "film". Maybe transparency-sheets" is the common name for certain objects, but it's not common enough for me as a non-native english speaker ;-). Would it be of any use to define one tag for all transparent craft media? That would put stuff like acrylic sheets, glass, cling film and transparency sheets into one category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the existing questions it seems like the [transparency-sheet](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transparency-sheet) tag is superfluous.

There are only 2 questions that use the [transparency](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transparency) tag in a questionable way:

1. [How to completely dye or tint or color clear transparency sheet?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/10902/6316) is still acceptable because it asks how to color transparent sheets and keep them transparent
2. [What glue should I use with acrylic and transparencies?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/10176/6316) uses the tag to mean transparency-sheets, but it still asks for a transparent glue.

Since they all ask for an art medium (glue or paint) that dries transparent, the [transparency](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transparency) tag is used correctly.

At the core of the questions people are asking for art media that are compatible with plastic sheets. Transparency-sheets are one type of plastic sheets, but there are are more similar questions in the [plastic](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plastic) tag. Retagging the questions and defining the [transparency](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transparency) tag to only mean the property of an object would be my preferred solution.

Comment: I think you nailed it. In a comment, you mention a catch-all tag for transparent craft materials. We probably don't need it. [transparency] referring to the optical property needs to be supplemented with additional tags for other key aspects of the question, like the kind of material. So a combination like [transparency]+[plastic] would work like a catch-all, covering transparency sheets, acrylic sheets, etc. If someone used just [transparency] to mean the sheets, they wouldn't be wrong, just light on tags. We may not need to retag anything, just define the tag. I'll work on that.

Comment: This seems like how tags should work. If your question is on getting your resin coating to stay transparent then tag [transparency] and [resin] (or plastic, etc.) and if it is on getting a glass object to look good in a watercolor than [transparency] and [water-colors] or [color theory].  Seems like tags are best thought of as additive, not specifically definitive.

Answer (score 1):

A specific proposal incorporating comment discussion with Elmy:

**The optical-property meaning**

Technically, [transparency] is probably a better term to use for that meaning, but it is ambiguous and would continue to be misused.  So use [transparent](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transparent), which would naturally not be used for the other meaning.

**The clear plastic film meaning**

I was originally thinking only of the transparency sheets, and that is what the applicable current questions refer to.  Elmy suggested in a comment [transparent-film].  The transparency sheets are a kind of transparent film, but that's not the term people would think of for them.  However, there are lots of crafting applications that involve some kind of clear film, and we could get questions about it.  I didn't spot any such questions yet, but I also didn't spot a good tag that could be used for them without pigeon-holing them under a tag people wouldn't readily associate with it.

So, have [transparency-sheets](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transparency-sheets) which is synonomized with a main tag of [transparent-film](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transparent-film).

Comment: Is it such a big deal that a user has to skip a few questions about, say, getting colors to look transparent in a painting, to find info on adding colors to a transparency projection?

Comment: @rebusB, now, sure. The question was about being proactive--get better tagging while there's only a few questions to fix. What happens when there are hundreds of questions to wade through (granted, that could be a ways into the future, maybe centuries?).